# Jenssegers MongoDB "like query" returning blank array on ISODate

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-4, jenssegers-mongodb

I have the following query but it's returning an empty array (I know for a fact that this query should return one record)

```
$created_at = date("Y-m");

$content = ContentModel::where('userId', $id->_id)
->where('created_at', 'like', "%{$created_at}%")
->orderBy('fav', 'DESC')
->get();
```

If I remove the `->where('created_at', 'like', "%{$created_at}%")` it returns everything fine but I want content that was of this year and month but the query doesn't work when I put that in.

The date in the database is ISODate format
`"created_at" : ISODate("2015-02-03T16:29:26.965Z")`

I'm taking a guess it's because of the ISODate format. How do I get the result I need?

Thanks

Comment: I checked the last query that was run: `{"query":"content.find({"userId":"545b08c10f6e807b0a8b4567","created_at":{"rege‌​x":"^2015-02$","flags":"i"}}, [])","bindings":[],"time":0.04}` This seems correct but nothings being returned

Comment: anybody?? please help I still couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
$created_at = new DateTime(date('F jS Y h:i:s A', strtotime('first day of ' . date('F Y'))));

$content = ContentModel::where('userId', $id->_id)
            ->where('created_at', '>', $created_at)
            ->orderBy('fav', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

In this code `$created_at` variable indicates the 1st of current month.

Comment: This does work and I am getting the result that I need but can you explain why the `like query` wasn't working? Will mark this as answer

Comment: Because the `created_at` field stores the date in ISODate format and it's not a normal string. So that we can't use like query here.